# web_set_certificate_ex in the AJAX script

Tags: ajax

I have recorded an AJAX truclient script.  I need to be able to play it for multiple users.  For web http protocol I use the web_set_certificate_ex to process my certs.

Is there a way to handle multiple users or is there a way to use the web_set_certificate_ex in the AJAX script.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to add sessions and go from there. Each request will be treated based on your session logic